# Plot randomness

Tags: r, random, plot

I am looking for help with generating this plot from a sequence of ones and zeros, in R. I am using it as one of a battery of tests to investigate whether a sequence is random or not (by looking for patterns in the noise). 
*Note: This is not homework!*

E.g.,

```
> y <- rnorm(3000, 1, 2)
> plot(y)
>plot(y~y)
```

My data is in this form:

```
 >str(hv10k)
 num [1:100000] 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
```

[image: rand1]

Update:

Following @Roman Luštrik suggestions this is what I've got so far:

700 approx coin toss:

[image: 700 approx coin toss]

100,000 coin toss:

[image: 100,000 coin toss]

Comment: Good...what's your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: And do not add tags into the title.

Comment: @RSouls: That's what tags are for.

Comment: You usually *follow* topics you're interested in and they get highlighted in the list. So putting the tags in the title would be redundant.

Comment: I think this is a discussion best left for meta, no? @Bobby changed the title and I will not add [R] to any further questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be

```
side <- 100
my.zero <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), side^2, replace = TRUE), side)
image(my.zero)
```

*EDIT*

You can play with the `prob` argument in `sample`.

```
side <- 100
my.zero <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), side^2, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 2)), side)
image(my.zero)
```

*EDIT 2*

```
y <- rnorm(10000, 1, 2)
y <- matrix(ifelse(y > 0, 1, 0), ncol = 100)
image(y, col = c("white", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: @Roman Luštrik Very interesting and some of that is new to me. I have to ask, if you see my edit, my data is not in a matrix and `(image(as.matrix(mydata))` doesn't work.

Comment: You have to put your data into a n*m (or n*n) matrix. Try `matrix(my.data, ncol = 1000)`.

Comment: I've added another edit with something closer to what you may be looking for.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik Many thanks. You've given me lots to work with there.

Comment: You can also check package `raster` that is actually tailor made for presenting matrices (spatial raster data).

Comment: `rasterImage` is a more-control-giving and way faster alternative to image for a such use.

Comment: Can you include your suggestion into my post for completeness (or make your own answer), @mbq?